# Azure Api Managment Basic tier for Internal and External

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Do you have any tips on how I should create Azure api management with say endpoitns

GET /users only accessible from internal network in our company
GET /cars for internal and external with ip filtering

How should we configure our environment so we don't make any mistakes at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Premium tier VNet isolation with IP filtering could be a way to go. But in Basic your only option is through enforcing different authentication mechanisms. If you know that /users will be accessed only by internal users that have distinct JWT tokens, or client certificates installed you could implement such checks in APIM for /users endpoint.